# Linear function.

Tags: functions

As an exercise, I'm trying to solve this question but I don't how to start. I would appreciate any form of help.

A cell phone plan has a basic charge of £25 a month.  The plan includes 400 free minutes and charges 5 pence for each additional minute of usage.  Write the monthly cost $C$ as a function of the number $x$ of minutes used.

I think the function should take the form $C=mU+b$ where $C$ is the cost, $m$ slope, $U$ is the usage and $b$ is the $y$ axis intercept.

The cost will stay the same for $\{ x \mid 0 \leq x \leq 400\}$, but how can express it as a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: If you use $\le 400$ minutes per month, cost just equals the basic charge $(C = b)$. If you use $> 400$ minutes per month, cost equals the basic charge plus $x$ minutes times $5p$ per minute. Can you see a way to write the last statement mathematically $(C = b + \dots)$ and the entire statement succinctly?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

A valid mathematical expression for this is ...

$C(U) = 25$ for $0 \le U \le 400$

$C(U) = 25 + 0.05 U $ for $U > 400$

Note that most functions you deal with early in your mathematical education have simple expressions like $y = sin(x)$ but the (loose) definition of a function is any expression that relates a single "output" value to a given "input" value.